# Object gets tinted by nearby Object's Color

Tags: rendering, materials, light

I'm trying to texturize an exterior scene but I have a problem and I don't know why.

I have a white building and there is another object with orange color under it. I know that it is normal that the white building get some orange color from the orange object.

My question is: Is there any away to avoid an object getting tinted by nearby objects' colors?

It has been happened before in another building, but it got fixed by its own. I'm working on Blender 2.8 Cycles Render Engine now.

Rendered scene:

[image: rendered scene]

White material node setup:

[image: white material node]

Orange material node setup:

[image: orange material node]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Please use [the inbuilt tools to add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) and not some random web services.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The answer for the question is quite simple - **Diffuse setting**, but the main problem might be the scene light setting, as part **Why do this behavior happen?** explained.

### Diffuse Ray

You can change the diffuse setting in `Properties Panel > Object > Cycles Settings >> Ray visibility : Diffuse`

The color you see is mainly from the diffuse ray in that orange color, by default it light up nearby objects like it is an emitting material. It is not a mistake but a natural behavior in real world. The most easily way to *FIX* this problem is to turn the diffuse behavior down. Making the material won't bounces light in the diffuse light path.

[image: diffuse ray setting]

#### Warning:

Turn off the diffuse ray will cause the rendered scene not accurate, making the render image seems to be wrong in some certain way.

### Material Node Setup

You can also change that behavior in material node editor as follow:
[image: Diffuse node]

With the **Input > Light Path** node, using diffuse value, you can change that material by using a **mix shader** with **is diffuse factor**. If you replace it by a white transparent shader, it will work as turn off the diffuse setting I mentioned above.

### Why do this behavior happen?

And another issue is that in this scene, you have your light and environment poor set up. Making it too simple from some certain light path, in this case, the orange diffuse bounces.

The main reason of that is maybe you are using point/sun light, and toward a specified angle, which cause the white wall capture a lot of bounces from orange roof top.

[image: Diffuse light]

You can change the angle of it, or you might also want to add more light around your scene, and object around it, making the light path more balance. Changing the radius of the point light may help as well.

Comment: But why this happends? Cant I control with which materials this happens?

Comment: It's called **ray tracing**, simulate the light in real world to get accurate result, you can find a lot of explanation on else where. You can control it in node editor, I edited my answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: And another issue is that in this scene, you have your light and environment poor set up. Making it too simple from some certain light path, in this case, the orange diffuse bounces. You might want to add more light  around your scene, and object around it, making the light path more balance.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test with this :)

Comment: If it (should) works, please consider to make this answer as accepted one. BTW, an environment light texture might work pretty good in your scene.

Comment: I would like to accept it, but i dont know how. I already gave it the tick